# What does 'wink neon' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Me, I’ve got a date with a dame **who winks neon**, serves bourbon,
>   lives light, loves rough, and lets me have all the best lines. ([BBC.
>   Radio 4](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/278))

Does the bold-faced part mean she winks and becomes neon, or she winks of the type of neon?

Comment: It means she winks in a neon way (or possibly blinks and creates the impression of neon?), but for the life of me I can't figure out what that means. I've never heard anything like it (or *winks [x]* of any sort), and I thought it could be a British expression but a google search for "winks neon" turned up nothing of note. What is this an excerpt of? I listened to the clip, but maybe with more surrounding context I could guess the meaning.

Comment: @WendiKidd, (1) Everyone wanted Zelda, even your husband. He preferred her cheap perfume to your expensive lies. You lied to build up your part in the story. All the fancy dialogue, lies. You couldn’t wait for the lead-ing roles to come along, could you? You had to take the fast route to the aristocracy of fame, an easy ride to top-shelf displays.

Comment: @WendiKidd, (2) I started in the pulps, lady, from the Dime Detectives I worked my way up. It was tough, but I earned it. You, you’d stop at nothing. You lied, cheated, and killed. You even appeared with the Three Stooges. I saw the script in this very house, the house you’re too small to live up to. “But, Phillip, we could share it.” No dice. You’ve got an appointment with the DA. Me, I’ve got a date with a dame who winks neon, serves bourbon, lives light, loves rough, and let’s me have all the best lines.

Comment: I think it means she's wearing neon eye makeup, and the author is trying to conjure up a lively mental image of her winking while wearing those sorts of colors around her eyes.  I could be wrong, but that's how it reads to me.

Comment: I'd agree with snailboat's comment, and add that 'neon' in a metaphor generally gives me a quick mental link to neon signs, as one may see on dance clubs, bars, or other nightlife venues. Either way, it's definitely a metaphor made up for this specific instance, and not a normal English idiom. This makes three native English speakers who've commented and aren't positive what they're getting at, though, so it doesn't appear to be a very effective metaphor either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a parody (but apparently a fairly affectionate one) of the "tough talk" of Dashiell Hammett's 1930's pulp detective novels; it's based on the end of "The Maltese Falcon".

Hammett's style is marked by marrying literary rhetorical devices such as metaphor to vernacular languge—"an easy ride to top-shelf displays". The key to this one is the parallelism:

> You’ve got an appointment with the DA. Me, I’ve got a date with a dame ...

That is, "You're going to jail; I'm going to my favorite bar."

As Emmabee says, "wink neon" refers to flashing neon signs; "blink" is more common, but "wink" is not unknown, and suits better with characterizing the bar as an old girlfriend.

If you enjoyed this, try Garrison Keillor's very funny parodies on [A Prairie Home Companion](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL82901077E4E58BF2).

Comment: Thank you very much. What a fancy words: a dame who winks neon! For this kind of words, in my middle school days, my mother tongue teacher said it would be far better to listen to radio than TV. But it's a rueful we don't have any radio dramas almost except BBC's.

Comment: @Listenever Radio drama's pretty much dead in the US, too; but the entire backlog of A Prairie Home Companion is available [here](http://prairiehome.publicradio.org/programs/). "Dame", by the way, is hardly a 'fancy' word: it's 1930s-50s slang for a woman. "There is Nothing Like a Dame" - *South Pacific*, 1949.

Comment: I’m very appreciated your introducing to the public radio show. When I heard his voice, it was very familiar. Yes! he is the reader in The Writer’s Almanac. I enjoyed his reading and tried to interpret those poems which is daily updated into my own tongue. But my English is so poor and, I thought, I need prior readings of long literature before short ones.